# How to Post value in dynamically popup textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to post this value to another php page and display the values.
How do I this?

PHP:

```
if(!empty($_POST["mytext"])) {
  for ($x=1; $x<=$a; $x++) { 
    echo $txtLine[$x] = $_POST['mytext'.$x]; 
  }
}
```

Code:

```js
function popuptxt() {
  var i = _("no_room").value;
  my_div.innerHTML = "";
  for (a = 1; a <= i; a++) {
    my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + 
      " <input type='text' style='width:50px;' name='mytext'+a> "
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="getvalue.php">
  <input type="text" style="width:200px;" 
     id="no_room" name="no_room" onChange="popuptxt()" required>
  <div id="my_div"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us your PHP code as well?

Comment: if(!empty($_POST["mytext"])) {for ($x=1; $x<=$a; $x++) { 
    
        echo $txtLine[$x] = $_POST['mytext'.$x]; 
    
}

Comment: You have undefined variables in your JS, work bad with variables in string (`a`), etc. First fix these typos, than try to pass value to another page.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read up on how to post and format questions. For example you seem to have not tagged this with whatever framework (underscore?) you use

Comment: What is $a ? Where it is defined ?

Comment: You're not posting `mytext`, you're posting `mytext0`, `mytext1` etc. Make sure your PHP code can deal with it, or just change the name `mytext[]` this will automatically turn it into an array when you receive it on the PHP side.

Comment: yes I am new to Stackoverflow,,,,,Sorry for my mistake,,,,I stacked with my school IT project...please help me

Comment: $a is some number like 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this to your javascript

```
function popuptxt() {
      var i = _("no_room").value;
      my_div.innerHTML = "";
      for (a = 1; a <= i; a++) {
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + 
          " <input type='text' style='width:50px;' name='mytext[]'> "
      }
    }
```

Update this to your php

```
if(!empty($_POST["mytext"])) {
  foreach ($_POST["mytext"] as $mytext) { 
    echo $txtLine[] = $mytext; 
  }
}
```

It may work for your condition